# CSS принудительный верхний z-индекс с родительским overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, css3, z-index, overflow

Я не могу разобраться, как переместить элемент, который находится под `.content-wrapper{ overflow:hidden; .content{position:absolute;}`на самый верх

Рассмотрим скриншот ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элемент изображения с фотографией человека размещается под элементом `.content`.

Но часть его головы на фотографии, которая выделена желтым цветом (указывает красная стрелка), скрыта из-за того, что родительский `.content-wrapper` имеет свойство `overflow: hidden`

Основная проблема в том, что я не могу изменить `hidden: overflow` на что-либо еще.

Реально ли решить такую проблему без использования JavaScript?

### === Дополнение 1 ====

Чтобы пояснить проблему, я составил фрагмент кода ниже:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:initial;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.content-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  margin:10px 0;
  min-height:350px;
}

.content{
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
}

.content.grayed{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.content.positioned{
  top:50px;
  left:180px;
  bottom:-50px; //negative positioned parts supposed to be hidden
  right:-50px;  //as .content-wrapper has overflow:hidden;
}

.content.positioned img{
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:-40vh; //but that is not supposed to be hidden out of .content-wrapper
  margin-left:10vw;
  min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
.wrapper
<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content grayed" style="transform: rotate(-35deg); padding:20px;">
<strong>.content</strong> with cut off edges - that is supposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

</div>
 Run code snippet
```

Неужели нет никакого решения?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/43280814/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я хотел бы добавить изображение снаружи и отрегулировать `position`, чтобы получить это. Измените `translation`, чтобы настроить взаимное положение элементов:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:initial;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.content-wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  margin:10px 0;
}

.content{
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
}
.content-wrapper-inner {
  min-height:350px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.content.grayed{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.content.positioned{
  top:50px;
  left:180px;
  bottom:-50px; //negative positioned parts supposed to be hidden
  right:-50px;  //as .content-wrapper has overflow:hidden;
}

.content.positioned img{
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:-40vh; //but that is not supposed to be hidden out of .content-wrapper
  margin-left:10vw;
  min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
.wrapper
<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content grayed" style="transform: rotate(-35deg); padding:20px;">
<strong>.content</strong> with cut off edges - that is supposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper

<div class="content-wrapper-inner">
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню.
Всё, что находится внутри элементов с `overflow:hidden`, будет обрезано его краями. И никак иначе. Исключение - выпадающая часть `<select>'ов`, которую браузер отображает средствами операционной системы, что позволяет показать их даже за пределами окна программы.
Нужно или `overflow:hidden` убирать, или содержимое наружу выносить.

Comment: это переводной топик вопрос-ответ. Только приветствуется, если вы дадите свой полный ответ с кодом. Галочка и плюсы за хороший ответ с комментариями ждут вас.

Comment: ответ уже дан выше. Я просто внес дополнение чтобы показать автору принципы.

Comment: без кода это просто слова, хотите давать советы, давайте совет с помощью работающего кода. Если вы хотите посоветовать автору, перейдите по ссылке на Enso в авторский топик.

Comment: Что ж с вами сложно-то так... Повторяю: работающий код УЖЕ приведен в ответе выше, нет смысла его дублировать. Ответ "что делать" УЖЕ дан, мое дополнение отвечает на вопрос "почему надо делать так". В какое место я тут должен засунуть код?